# Remove 'All Files' option from HTML file input and limit to .json type when using File System Access API

Tags: javascript, json

I am using File System Access API to disable all files options when uploading files, and want to be accepted only .json files but it brings under All Files (*.*) As in pic:

[image]

I don't know if I'm entering wrong "application/json", maybe should be something else instead of this.
Official documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API#examples
Can someone help?
My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Open file</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="getFile()">Open file</button>
        <script>
            const pickerOpts = {
                types: [
                    {
                        accept: {
                            "application/json": [".json"],
                        },
                    },
                ],
                excludeAcceptAllOption: true,
                multiple: false,
            };

            let fileHandle;
            async function getFile() {
                [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker(pickerOpts);
                // run code with our fileHandle
            }
            console.log(fileHandle);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine in my browser. I'm guessing it's a compatibility issue, since the File System Access API is still an experimental API.

Comment: What browser are you using? I'am using Chrome 105.

Comment: MacOS 12.6, Chrome 105.0.5195.125.

Comment: And you are only seeing JSON File (*.json)? and not All files, the sam as in my screenshot?

Comment: Usually OS will always have the "All files" for usability concerns you cannot remove it. If you worried about user selecting the wrong file you can trigger a validation when user selects a file